# How to share a library in client and server packages

Tags: reactjs, express, npm

I am developing a full stack application with expressjs on the server and react on the front end.

Currently my code structure looks like this

```
project
--client
----src/
----package.json
----tsconfig.json

--server
----src/
----package.json
----tsconfig.json
```

I want to create a new library that holds all the common interfaces between client and server into a separate third package.

What is the right way to create this package? I tried using npm link and path references but both times I got errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can try separately into client directory and open command line and excute "npm i package Name"